Shading lines/artifacts in the viewport/render mode
I don't know why, but some lines appear in the shading on the object representing a triangle. All points of this side lie on the same plane (in the same X location). Tried to add weighted normals but it only fixed the situation in the viewport. I can show in detail all the modifications that I added.



It looks a if you may have some odd topology judging by the lines on the front corner of your first image. Please share your Blend file so that we can have a look.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. An image of it in Edit mode in wireframe (Shift-Z) might also help.

Okay I added it

I checked the topology and yes, it is the culprit of the problem. But what kind of topology should I do with bevel modifier?

In Edge mode, try dissolving the angled edge on the face and see if that helps. Incidentally the triangles shown on the rendered image that you've added are because of the rotation angle of the sun on the World Sky texture.

I used simple straight cuts, and I think it won't mess up the shading instead of diagonal connections between close points using the function Split Concave Faces or Triangulate Faces. I think this solution fits. Someone can correct me, of course.

